# Backbone.js on Rails - Access data in Rails outside of the Backbone model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js, rails-activerecord

I have a Backbone.js application with RoR for the backend.

The typical backbone.js setup is it gets the data from the table, and updates/saves data to that same table.  However, my backbone model is made of a universal list of vendors, and I want a user to be able to "select" a vendor, which would dump into a DIFFERENT table, called user_selected_vendors.

I don't even know how to set this up in backbone.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add some code examples to your question, it would make things clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to give specific advice without seeing some code examples.

In general though, you should think of your Rails backend as providing JSON service endpoints for your Backbone code to talk with.  When your Rails app receives requests from the Backbone front end, you can do whatever is necessary with the request data.  You are not limited to providing JSON endpoints which directly map to your database tables.

Also, based on the name of your `user_selected_vendors` table, it seems like you are not taking advantage of the ActiveRecord associations.  What you may really want is something along the lines of adding `has_many :vendors` association to your `User` model.  See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-association